# Can an IID sequence be a martingale?

Tags: conditional-expectation, martingales, independence, filtrations

I was looking into Doob's upcrossing inequality, which says that for a supermartingale $X$ and real numbers $b > a$, $$(b-a)\mathbb{E}[N_n([a,b], X)] \leq \mathbb{E}[(X_n -a)^-],$$
where $N_n([a,b], X)$ is the number of upcrossings $[a,b]$ by the sequence $X$ by time $n$. If $X_n$ were IID random variables, then the right hand side of this inequality would always be constant, but I would imagine that the left hand side would be increasing at a constant rate. This would indicate to me that it is impossible for an IID sequence to be a supermartingale (let alone a martingale). Unfortunately, I can't see why this is impossible just from the raw definitions of a (super)martingale. Is anyone able to help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(X_n)$ is i.i.d then $E(X_{n+1}|X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=EX_{n+1}$ and we cannot have $E(X_{n+1}|X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=X_{n}$ unless $X_n$is a constant. Hence, the only i.i.d. sequence which is also  martingale is of the type $\{c,c,\cdots\}$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: Must it be true that $E(X_{n + 1}| X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n) = X_n$ for a martingale? I am using the general definition of a martingale which requires that $E(X_{n +1}|\mathcal{F}_n) = X_n$ where $\mathcal{F}_n$ is the filtration and $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable.

Comment: Yes, your definition of martinagle  implies that $E(X_{n+1}|X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=X_{n}$ since $\sigma (X_1,X_2,...,X_n)\subset\mathcal F_n$. .@HarryPartridge

Comment: Yes, thanks I have confirmed this for myself. Indeed $E(E(X_{n +1}| \mathcal{F}_n)|X_n) = E(X_{n +1}|X_n)$ by the tower law, and $E(X_n | X_n) = X_n$, so putting these together we get the result.